# User authentication should be only once

Tags: android

I am developing an android application which should authenticate user only once in his mobile after installing the app. It should not ask the details for the second time. For this I have used shared preferences by setting a Boolean value. But it,s not working. Is there any suggestions here.. thanks friends !! My code is here

```
SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("Register", true);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Put the code part where do you do the check if user has login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use it this way :

in your `onCreate()`  use :

```
if (isFirstTime()) {
    // do what you want to do only once 
}
```

to call the below :

```
private boolean isFirstTime()
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean ranBefore = preferences.getBoolean("RanBefore", false);
    if (!ranBefore) {
        // first time
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", true);
        editor.commit();
    }
    return !ranBefore;
}
```

Comment: I have to write that registration should be only once. Can you show how it would be?

Comment: what do you mean by "to write that registration should be only once
"? do you mean that you want to set an alertbox or a Toast to tell the user that? and that message will appear only once as well?

Comment: in the startup Activity for your application

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of using `SharedPreference` is correct.Put the below coad snippet in your `oncreate()` method of the `Activity`.

```
SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        register = prefs.getBoolean("Register",false);

        if(!register)
        {
            //register user
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("Register", register);
            editor.commit();
        }
        else{
            //continue with the rest
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

the first time :

```
settings.edit().putBoolean("Register", true).commit();
```

and in onCreate you do the test

```
if(!settings.getBoolean("Register",false))
    //it isn't the first time
```

So the full code :

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
if(!settings.getBoolean("Register",false)){
     //it isn't the first time
}
else{
    settings.edit().putBoolean("Register", true).commit();
}
```